# Bash contains not working

Tags: mysql, bash, version, contains

I have tried this:

http://timmurphy.org/2013/05/13/string-contains-substring-in-bash/

and none of them is working for me.

My code is:

```
     if [[ "$MYSQLRPMSHARED" == *"$MYSQLDB"* ]]; then
         echo "True"
     else
         echo "Failed."
     fi
```

I get the MYSQLRPMSHARED  and MYSQLDB variables via these commands:

```
MYSQLDB=$(mysql -uroot -p -e "select @@version" | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g')
MYSQLRPMSHARED=($(rpm -qa | grep MySQL-shared))
```

And their results are:

```
5.5.28
MySQL-shared-compat-5.5.28-1.rhel5
```

But when I trigger the IF, I get "Failed." When I put 5.5.28 in the IF statement instead of $MYSQLDB then I get the "True" answer instead of "Failed."

Where is the problem? I am using 3.2.25 bash.

Comment: Check if your MYSQLDB variable has any new line character..

Comment: Works for me in 4.3.42(3).

Comment: `$( ... )` should strip trailing newlines; my guess would be a carriage return. In any case, probably some nonprinting character(s) in the MYSQLDB variable. Try `printf "%q\n" "$MYSQLDB"` -- if it prints `$'5.5.28\r'`, you've got a return at the end of the variable value.

Comment: It prints $'\n5.5.28'

Comment: When I use tr -d '\n', the IF statement works but I get empty line when trying to echo "MYSQLDB".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete non-numeric line and retain only version using

```
MYSQLDB=$(mysql -uroot -p -e "select @@version" | awk -F"[ -]" '/[0-9]/{print $1}')
```